# How to bind image control to a file selected by user?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, winrt-xaml

I have an image file selected by user whose name is 'img'. How can I bind my Image control (given below) to this file?

```
<Image Source = "{Binding ImagePath}" />
```

I wrote:

```
ImagePath = new Uri(img.Path);
```

But it does not work. Can anyone help me?

Comment: I did it like keyboardP said and it worked. Thanks for helping :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After your image is loaded, create a `BitmapImage`.

```
 var bi = new BitmapImage();
 var fstream = await selectedFile.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read);
 bi.SetSource(fstream);
 BImage = bi;
```

Then make sure your `BImage` property notifies the UI. I renamed `ImagePath` to `BImage` to clarify that it's not using the `Path` directly, but you can call it whatever you like.

```
private BitmapImage _bImage;
public BitmapImage BImage
{
   get { return _bImage; }
   set
   {
      _bImage= value;
      NotifyPropertyChanged("BImage");
   }
}
```

(Your XAML)

```
<Image Source = "{Binding BImage}" />
```